# A way to mark an ad as not relevant to me

Tags: feature-request, advertising

With google ads there is an option present to mark an ad as not relevant to me and I fill in a small questionaire if I hit the little x on the ads.

There are some ads that are repeatedly presented to me by commercial partners on this site that are simply not relevant to me. I know I can do a thumbs up or down, but that doesn't suit me, because it's not a bad ad, it's just not relevant to me and it could better be served to people to which it's relevant.

I have for example no interest in Microsoft Azure services for my own reasons, but others might.
If I could mark it as not relevant to me it can be better targeted to people to which it's relevant, and I get more interesting ads that are more suited to my interests.

**Edit**

I just learned this feature exists, I ask then that there be tooltips added to the thumbs up and thumbs down to explain the purpose of the thumbs up and down, that down doesn't per se mean bad ad, but works as a not relevant indicator.

Comment: When you click the thumbs down, an extra dialogue appears, saying "No problem. We won't show you that ad again. Why didn't you like it?" One of the canned reasons is "Uninteresting", which would seem to be what you want, I think?

Comment: Hmmm, the thumbs down felt to me more like a downvote, a bad ad, not suiteable for this site/community. But I didn't feel the ad was bad, just not relevant. Maybe I'm too used to the upvote = good, downvote = bad/disagree functioning. There wasn't a tooltip either when I hoved over it that explained the function to me.